# Is there a way to use portal-vue package with vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

I am using portal-vue for my project and I've updated it to vue 3.
When I try to install portal-vue I get an Error
[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0J2b.png)

I was wondering if there is a way to use the portal-vue with vue3?

Comment: vuejs3 comes with teleport component out of box so there might not be a need for portal-vue. But of course it depends on what feature you are using from portal-vue

Answer (score 0):

there is actually no support for vue 3.

You have to downgrade your vue version to use portal-vue again.

See the open support ticket from 2020: https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue/issues/300

> Yeah. This is a Vue 2 plugin. I'll release a vue 3 compatible version in time.
>
> LinusBorg commented on 14 May 2020

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and for the git ticket!.

Answer (score 0):

I made a new [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-portal) for `Vue 3` inspired by `portal-vue`. Try it out.

Comment: More people should know about this!  Also, the OG Portal-Vue has an alpha version for Vue 3 -- docs: https://next.portal-vue.linusb.org/

Answer (score 0):

Teleport is what you are after - it is now built into the framework in Vue 3:

https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/teleport.html